# angularjs : can't auto-select an option in select tag when opening html page

Tags: angularjs, select

I m displaying an array of years (2014,2015,2016,2017) with the select tag. I want 2014 to be selected when my page is displayed.

html :

```
<select ng-model="search.year" ng-options="year for year in years" null-is-undefined ng-selected="search.year">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

controller :

```
budgetApp.controller('BudgetController', ['$scope', 'resolvedBudget', 'Budget', '$log',
function ($scope, resolvedBudget, Budget, $log) {
     $scope.years = [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017];
     $scope.search.year = '2014'
     {blablabla}
    }]);
```

When running the app, it says that $scope.search.year is undefined, i dont know why.

Comment: could you show your controller ? and are you calling it ? ng-controller="..."

Comment: My controller is working fine in the html file for everything except this problem.

Comment: Remove the `ng-selected`

Comment: `$scope.search.year = '2014'` there is no object search in your scope. either initialize search to an empty object or use `$scope.search = {year : '2014'}`. I don't have my dev tools so couldn't confirm this

Comment: It's probably because you have an `ng-selected` directive attribute on a select element. The selected value of your `ng-options` should be handled by your `ng-model` binding. `ng-selected` is for `option` elements.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments remove `ng-selected` which is for OPTIONS [see ng-selected Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MrL5d/)**

html

```
<div ng-app='App'>
    <div ng-controller="BudgetController">
        <select ng-model="search.year" null-is-undefined ng-options="year for year in years" >
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var budgetApp = angular.module('App', []);

budgetApp.controller('BudgetController', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
     $scope.years = [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017];
     $scope.search = {year:2013};
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, one more question for those who use this more stylish Select component (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select). I can't get my element selected. If by chance someone here uses it and knows how to get it work...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution http://jsbin.com/juxebewu/7/

```
<html ng-app='App'>
    <body>

    <div ng-controller="BudgetController">
        <select ng-model="search.year" ng-options="year as year for year in years" ng-init="search.year=2014">
        </select>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
var budgetApp = angular.module('App', []);


budgetApp.controller('BudgetController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     $scope.years = [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017];
}]);
```